# find installed postgresql servers in local machine

Tags: c#, npgsql

Is it possible to write code to detect the list of installed PostgreSQL servers in the local machine? With SQL Server this is possible in C# by using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi -- Is there something similar with Npgsql? I'm looking to give the user a list of server instances in the current machine and let them select one.

**Update**:
I found this [message](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4BF7A62D.5030008@postnewspapers.com.au) from 2010 that suggests it's not possible to search for installed instances of PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding that PostgreSQL leaves entries in the registry, with one folder per version installed. Each folder contains a "data" path. The data path has a file with settings. One of the lines will specify the port number.